# Remote Finish an Android Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have three activities, **a, b, c**.  Activity **b** will start activity **c**. In activity **c** when i press the **back** key, activity **c** will finish() and activity **b** will show just as it was left.

That is not that hard, what i am wanting to do is when i finish() activity **c**, i want to finish() activity **b** at the same time in order to show activity **a**.

Does anyone have any idea on how to finish an activity from another activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this best way is to use startActivityForResult and onActivityResult in conjugation.

From Activity A, start activity B and then from B start activity C for a result using startActivityForResult()

In Activity C, when the user triggers back or Destroy()

set a result that will inform A to finish as well,

Call finish() in C.

When B receives that result from C, B calls finish() on itself as well.

In the parent activity, while triggering the child activity, use the following command:-

```
startActivityForResult(intent,variable(int));
```

and override the onActivityResult Method in the following manner in Activity B:-

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode==2){
        finish();
    }
}
```

Now, in the child activity C, override onStop and onDestroy in the following manner:-

```
protected void onStop() {
    setResult(2);
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    setResult(2);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, Before moving to Activity C finish the Activity B. So, next time when you click on ack button directly it will move to Activity A like the follwong code:

```
      Intent in = new Intent(B.class, C.class);
       startActivity(in)
        finish();
```

Comment: What i am wanting to do is show activity B on back button and activity A on OK button.

Comment: from the above code, when u click on Back Button it will redirect to Activity A directly from Activity C

Comment: and also finish(); the Activity C when u click on Back Button otherwise u may get some Excepions